# Deploying Treeline

Tags: sails.js, treeline

I'm trying to deploy a Treeline app on my Ubuntu/Digital Ocean server with no luck.

I have worked successfully with sails (using "forever") before and tried to install treeline the same way.

```
npm install treeline -g
```

But after the installation, when trying to do something else, it always returns:

```
treeline.py: cannot connect to X server
```

I don't know if this error is due to my lack of experience deploying node or the earlier stage of the treeline project (which, on the other hand, is really awesome).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying a Treeline app is exactly the same as deploying a Sails app, because the files that get synched down from the Treeline server *are* Sails apps--they were just generated for you instead of you having to write the code.  You don't need to `npm install treeline -g` on your server; that's only for previewing your app locally as you make changes to it on [treeline.io](http://treeline.io).  Instead, when you're ready to deploy, just follow whatever procedure that worked for your previous Sails apps and it will work for your Treeline app.

As far as the `treeline.py` error--that appears to be coming from a conflicting file pre-installed on Ubuntu!